# How to use another existing Firefox profile (the easy way)

Tags: windows, firefox, profile

After "cross-grading" my 32-bit Firefox to 64-bit failed on Windows (the upgraded Firefox still was placed in "Programs (x86)"), I decided to uninstall it and reinstall it.
Now it is located in the proper directory, but it seems Firefox has created a new user profile silently, without giving the user an option to use the existing profile(s).

"Digging around" a bit I found:

- There's an `installs.ini` in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox` containing two "installations" (those magic hex sequences) with one `Default` profile each
- There's an `profiles.ini` in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox` containing two installations, one with three profiles, the other with one profile
- In `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles` I see three profile directories
- In `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles` I see two profile directories

Before I try messing up the files with an editor, I'd like to ask is there a way to make Firefox *see*, *use*, or *import* previous profiles?

I know the `-ProfileManager` option, but that does not display profiles from previous installations.
When using it, it knows about three profiles: `new`, `default`, and `default-esr` (I'm currently using Firefox 102.6.0esr)

But there is no further data on "who's who".

I'd like to continue using the profile I had used before reinstalling Firefox.

Possibly useful links are:

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles (I would still have to find out "who's who")
- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/recovering-important-data-from-an-old-profile (Still the "who's who" problem)

Comment: See also https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1806626 (enhancement request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use my previous profile using the facts and procedure given below:

- The profiles in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles` have more content than those with the same name in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`.
- `9sy1k2tf.default-esr` is newer (by content) than `mpm85xoi.default`
- File `installs.ini` contains two installations: `308046B0AF4A39CB` seems to be the new one, and `E7CF176E110C211B` seems to be the old one.
- In `profiles.ini` section `[Install308046B0AF4A39CB]` contains three profile assignments, while `[InstallE7CF176E110C211B]` contains only one:

```ini
[Install308046B0AF4A39CB]
Default=Profiles/9sy1k2tf.default-esr
Locked=1

[Profile2]
Name=default-esr
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/9sy1k2tf.default-esr

[Profile1]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/mpm85xoi.default
Default=1

[Profile0]
Name=new
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/l27m949z.default

[InstallE7CF176E110C211B]
Default=Profiles/mpm85xoi.default

[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1
Version=2
```

Examining the dates of the three profiles (i.e.: directory content) in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`, I found out:

```
9sy1k2tf.default-esr: new
l27m949z.default: very old
mpm85xoi.default: old
```

So the profile named `default` would be my old one.
I started `firefox -ProfileManager` to see the profile selection dialog, and from there I chose to use the `default` profile for future invocations, and my data was magically there again!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is replace the *contents* of the new profile folder
with the *contents* of the old folder.

The random names of the folders may be different on both computers,
but it's the contents that matter.

Save the new folder's contents before replacing them, just in case.

Comment: Actually I found a procedure that did not involve any copying; see https://superuser.com/a/1758702/964771. Life would be much easier if Firefox would present a profile selection dialog together with some profile metadata helping to find out "who's who".

Comment: Copying is really the easiest solution - I do it whenever I change computers.

Comment: Yes, but I did not change the computer!

Comment: Yes; we realize that